# scala.MatchError: null error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am new to Scala and having difficulty figuring out the issue with this code.

```
x.map{case (x1: Any, x2: Any,x3: String) => x1}.count()
```

Throwing

```
scala.MatchError: null error
```

this is the definition of `x`

```
scala> x.cache()
res111: x.type = MapPartitionsRDD[522] at map at <console>:49

scala> x
res109: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Any, Any, String)] = MapPartitionsRDD[522] at map at <console>:49

scala> x.count()
res112: Long = 64508825
```

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: That means you have `null` in your data. Why not just `x.map(_._1).count` ?

Comment: @philantrovert it will give nullpointer exception

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Nope, it shouldn't.

Comment: I just tried it ;) `val x = sc.parallelize(Seq(("3", 1, "t"), (3.0, "1", "t"), null))` which also gives the same error that the OP has encountered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message

> > scala.MatchError: null

clearly indicates that there is a `null` value intead of `(Any, Any, String)`

So you should be *filtering null values before the count*

```
x.filter(_ != null).map{case (x1: Any, x2: Any,x3: String) => x1}.count()
```

## unsure of null

If you are not sure if your data has a null value or not then you can *change the match case* as following and do the *filter after match case*

```
x.map{_ match {
  case (x1: Any, x2: Any,x3: String) => x1
  case _ => "not matched"
}}.filter(_ != "not matched").count()
```

Comment: OP is able to get the count as shown in the question. I'm guessing you can reproduce the error using data like `Seq(("3", 1, "t"), (3.0, "1", "t"), (null, null, null.asInstanceOf[String]) )`. Your filter conditions need to be changed.

Comment: @philantrovert `sc.parallelize(Seq(("3", 1, "t"), (3.0, "1", "t"), null)).count()` would give me count too as 3. And why the filter condition needs a change? if you clarify the reason I shall change it

Comment: @philantrovert if you have rdd as `Seq(("3", 1, "t"), (3.0, "1", "t"), (null, null, null.asInstanceOf[String]) )` then we get error as `scala.MatchError: (null,null,null) (of class scala.Tuple3)` but OP has `scala.MatchError: null ` error

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems there were null in the fields. your solution solved it.